# How to upgrade npm package for ngx-bootstrap 3.2.0 to latest 4.0.0?

Tags: datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

How to upgrade `npm` package for `ngx-bootstrap` 3.2.0 to latest 4.0.0?

I tried upgrading using, `npm update ngx-bootstrap --save`, which upgrades package to version 3.3.0 but not 4.0.0, after which datepicker stops working and makes the browser(chrome) non-responsive.

Can you let me know if anyone has any possible solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

`npm i ngx-bootstrap@next --save`
or
`npm i ngx-bootstrap@latest --save`